# Sampling from pandas dataframe according to particular column value

Tags: python, pandas

I have pandas dataframe df that contains search_id
and I want to randomly sample the df into training and test set where training and test set both have different search_ids.
Search_id is not unique and there are multiple entries corresponding to each search_id but I want that training and test data should have different search_ids. 
What I could find was general sampling but I did not find how I can use search_id to split:

```
train=df.sample(frac=0.8,random_state=200)
test=df.drop(train.index)
```

Comment: why we need to do this ? You are manipulate the split which will cause the bias and variance with future training

Comment: Because it is a ranking problem and I need to look at search_id query as the unique point.

Answer (score 0):

If you do want to do that we can using `sklearn`

```
from sklearn.model_selection import (TimeSeriesSplit, KFold, ShuffleSplit,
                                     StratifiedKFold, GroupShuffleSplit,
                                     GroupKFold, StratifiedShuffleSplit)
GS = GroupShuffleSplit(n_splits=1, test_size=0.3)
tid,trid=next(GS.split(X=df, y=df['Target'], groups=df['Group_ID']))
train , test = df.iloc[tid] , df.iloc[trid]
```